# how to make images in an arraylist not repeat

Tags: android

how to make these images not repeat? I try using hashset but it didn't work please help me. i only need to show 1 picture and will not repeat everytime the button is clicked and when all the picture were shown the app will end help me guys. Thanks in advance for giving an answer. here's my code

```
ImageView imgname, imgname1;

ArrayList<Integer> animals;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgname = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgname);
    imgname1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgname1);


    imgname1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    animals = new ArrayList<>();


    animals.add(109);//fish
    animals.add(110);//fish
    animals.add(112);//fish
    animals.add(113);//fish
    animals.add(114);//fish
    animals.add(111);//fish
    animals.add(209);//arachnid




    imgname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //shuffle the images
            Collections.shuffle(animals);

                assignImages(animals.get(0), imgname1);
                imgname1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
}


public void assignImages(int animals, ImageView image){
    switch (animals){
        case 109:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ears);
            break;
        case 110:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.eyes);
            break;
        case 112:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hand);
            break;
        case 113:
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hearing);
            break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `images` which are already shown and copy them to new `temp` array to maintain original array untouched

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
temp.addAll(animals);
imgname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //shuffle the images
           if(temp.size() > 0){
                Collections.shuffle(temp);
                int imageTobeShown = temp.get(0); 
                assignImages(imageTobeShown , imgname1);
                temp.remove(imageTobeShown);
                imgname1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }else{
              //ended showing all images   
           }
      }
    });
```

Comment: this line is an error itemp.remove(imageTobeShown); but thanks for the help

Comment: I've updated `animals.get(0)` to  `temp.get(0)`, try it now and do paste what kind of error you are seeing?

Comment: at com.example.scitime.animals2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:55) this is the error that i get. And the code in line 55 is temp.remove(imageTobeShown);

Answer (score 0):

I done it by doing this ...

final ArrayList temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.addAll(animals);

```
    imgname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(temp.size() > 0){
                Collections.shuffle(temp);
                assignImages(temp.get(0) , imgname1);
                temp.remove(temp.get(0));
                imgname1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please press back again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```